# import css file from node_modules using require()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

Working in a Vue app
I am trying to import a css file dynamically from a couple of dependencies in node_modules.

Using a `require('path')` with a static string works fine and load my css file.
As soon as I try to pass the function argument to the require() function, it does not work.

```js
const getFontDeclaration = (path) => {
  {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
       // a static string works fine
      require('@foo/own-package-name/dist/assets/css/font-face.css');

      // using an argument does not work
      require(path);

      // import(path)
      // does not work either

      // while this work fine too
      import('@foo/own-package-name/dist/assets/css/font-face.css')     
        .then(() => {
          resolve();
        })
    });
  }
};
```

Any clue or direction ? Bit confused between the use of import() and require()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require` does not work perfectly dynamically, because webpack does not know the path of your `path` argument. However, if you add some kind of template literal in your `require` it will work (e.g. `my-fonts/${path}`).

`import` imports something dynamically and lazy.

You can find more details on Webpack `import` function [here](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/).

Comment: Thanks ! It will only work if the content passed to `require()` is starting with a string. `const reqPath = url.replace('@foo/', '')`and then `require('@foo' + reqPath)`

Comment: You're welcome :) You can make it more concise with a template literal ;)

Answer (score 0):

For sake of clarity

```js
const getFontDeclaration = (path) => {
  // using a variable directly will not work
  require(path);

  // removing a part of the path and prepending it with a static string will work
  const reqPath = url.replace('@foo/', '');
  require(`@foo/${reqPath}`);
}
```